# Error when try to start local Hotspot on android part of a flutter app

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-method-channel

I've got a flutter app in which I want to start the hotspot of the device. So I have to write some platform specific code on android to use hotspot.

I got this that compiles without a problem:

```
try {
            if (call.method == "startLocalOnlyHotspot")  {
                var wifiManager: WifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
                
                wifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(object : WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {
                    override fun onStarted(localOnlyHotspotReservation: WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation) {
                        super.onStarted(localOnlyHotspotReservation)
                        result.success(localOnlyHotspotReservation)
                    }

                    override fun onStopped() {
                        super.onStopped()
                        result.success(null)
                    }

                    override fun onFailed(reason: Int) {
                        super.onFailed(reason)
                        result.success(null)
                    }
                }, Handler())
                // log the results
                Log.d("Hotspot", "Hotspot started")
                // result.success(ApManager.configApState(this)) 
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            result.error("ERROR", e.message, null)
        }
```

But when I call this code from flutter with this:

```
await platform.invokeMethod('startLocalOnlyHotspot');
```

the app crashes with I think this main error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value:
> 'android.net.wifi.WifiManager$LocalOnlyHotspotReservation@f603f75' of
> type 'class android.net.wifi.WifiManager$LocalOnlyHotspotReservation'

But if it's not that, I put the full error stack here :

> W/WifiManager(28567): com.kwikwink.kw_delivery attempted call to
> setWifiApEnabled: enabled = false D/Hotspot (28567): Hotspot started
> D/WifiManager(28567): LocalOnlyHotspotCallbackProxy: handle message
> what: 0 msg: { when=0 what=0 obj=* ID: -2 SSID: AndroidShare_2246
> PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 0 HIDDEN: false PMF:
> false D/WifiManager(28567):  NetworkSelectionStatus
> NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLED D/WifiManager(28567):  hasEverConnected:
> false D/WifiManager(28567):  KeyMgmt: WPA2_PSK Protocols:
> D/WifiManager(28567):  AuthAlgorithms: D/WifiManager(28567):
> PairwiseCiphers: D/WifiManager(28567):  GroupCiphers:
> D/WifiManager(28567):  PSK: * D/WifiManager(28567): Enterprise config:
> D/WifiManager(28567): eap NULL D/WifiManager(28567): phase2
> "auth=NULL" D/WifiManager(28567): IP config: D/WifiManager(28567): IP
> assignment: UNASSIGNED D/WifiManager(28567): Proxy settings:
> UNASSIGNED D/WifiManager(28567):  cuid=-1 luid=-1 lcuid=0
> userApproved=USER_UNSPECIFIED noInternetAccessExpected=false
> D/WifiManager(28567): recentFailure: Association Rejection code: 0
> D/WifiManager(28567): D/WifiManager(28567): samsungSpecificFlags:
> D/WifiManager(28567): semAutoWifiScore: 0 D/WifiManager(28567):
> isVendorAp : false D/WifiManager(28567): recoverableRSSI: -200
> D/WifiManager(28567): inRecoverArea: false D/WifiManager(28567):
> disabledTime: 0 D/WifiManager(28567): notInRangeTime: 0
> D/WifiManager(28567): isUsableInternet: false D/WifiManager(28567):
> skipInternetCheck: -1 D/WifiManager(28567): notAskAgainCheck: false
> D/WifiManager(28567): nextTargetRssi: 0 D/WifiManager(28567):
> isCaptivePortal: false D/WifiManager(28567): isAuthenticated: false
> D/WifiManager(28567): loginUrl: null D/WifiManager(28567):
> autoReconnect: 1 D/WifiManager(28567): isRecommended: false
> D/WifiManager(28567): isHomeProviderNetwork: false
> D/WifiManager(28567):  WapiCertIndex: 0 D/WifiManager(28567):
> WapiPskType: 0 D/WifiManager(28567): isWeChatAp : false
> D/WifiManager(28567): entryRssi24GHz : -78 D/WifiManager(28567):
> entryRssi5GHz : -75
> target=android.net.wifi.WifiManager$LocalOnlyHotspotCallbackProxy$1 }
> D/AndroidRuntime(28567): Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime(28567):
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(28567): Process:
> com.kwikwink.kw_delivery, PID: 28567 E/AndroidRuntime(28567):
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value:
> 'android.net.wifi.WifiManager$LocalOnlyHotspotReservation@f603f75' of
> type 'class android.net.wifi.WifiManager$LocalOnlyHotspotReservation'
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:297)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeSuccessEnvelope(StandardMethodCodec.java:63)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:267)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> com.kwikwink.kw_delivery.MainActivity$configureFlutterEngine$1$1.onStarted(MainActivity.kt:33)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> android.net.wifi.WifiManager$LocalOnlyHotspotCallbackProxy$1.handleMessage(WifiManager.java:3755)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
> E/AndroidRuntime(28567):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) I/Process
> (28567): Sending signal. PID: 28567 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device.

If anyone can help me with this it could be lovely. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
  result.success(localOnlyHotspotReservation)
```

You cannot return a Java object (in this case `WifiManager$LocalOnlyHotspotReservation`) from a method call - just supported values (integers, strings, lists, maps, etc).

If you'd like to return some particular value from there, like the SSID, you'd need to extract it in the native code and return that (supported) type. For example:

```
  result.success(localOnlyHotspotReservation.getSoftApConfiguration().getWifiSsid().toString())
```

Comment: I try your solution but it didn't work but I don't have the same error now. I wrote this code to return the ssid  and passphrase :
`var hotSpotSuccess = localOnlyHotspotReservation.getSoftApConfiguration().getWifiSsid().toString() + "|" + localOnlyHotspotReservation.getSoftApConfiguration().getPassphrase()
                            result.success(hotSpotSuccess)`
but i got this error : 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getSoftApConfiguration()Landroid/net/wifi/SoftApConfiguration;`

Comment: Probably means your phone isn't on API 30 - try using `getWifiConfiguration` instead. That's an Android issue, rather than a Flutter method channel issue. Now that you know how to return values from Flutter native method calls, you could return a fixed string for now for testing and ask an Android only question about how to handle the API 30 issue.

Comment: I will try to do that though. your help have been huge thanks a lot !

Comment: You were right it surly was an issue with the api lvl, the method `getWifiConfiguration` work perfectly fine